# Perl: parsing text output into array of hashes

Tags: arrays, perl, for-loop, dynamic, hash

i'm not experienced and not very good at writing code and I have been stuck on this issue for a little while now. I have searched stackoverflow before but couldn't really find anything that matches my issue so thought of trying to get some help this way.

I want to build a script that analyzes text output from a certain command and put that into an array of hashes so i can do stuff with it.

I have text output like this:

```
      1 : DISPLAY AUTHREC GROUP('GROUP1')
 AMQ8864I: Display authority record details.
    PROFILE(SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE)     ENTITY(GROUP1)
    ENTTYPE(GROUP)                          OBJTYPE(QUEUE)
    AUTHLIST(BROWSE,CHG,CLR,DLT,DSP,GET,INQ,PUT)
 AMQ8864I: Display authority record details.
    PROFILE(SYSTEM.MQEXPLORER.REPLY.MODEL)
    ENTITY(GROUP1)                         ENTTYPE(GROUP)
    OBJTYPE(QUEUE)
    AUTHLIST(BROWSE,CHG,CLR,DLT,DSP,GET,INQ,PUT)
 AMQ8864I: Display authority record details.
    PROFILE(self)                           ENTITY(GROUP1)
    ENTTYPE(GROUP)                          OBJTYPE(QMGR)
    AUTHLIST(ALTUSR,CHG,CONNECT,DLT,DSP,INQ,SET)
```

I want to store each record as a hash on an array of hashes.
this is how i currently do it (please don't be negative about how i wrote this, there are probably 100 better ways to do this but i'm still learning so keep that in mind please, suggestions to improve are always welcome) :

```
    my @authrecs;   
    my @authrecoutput;  #this array contains the text output as displayed above, each line in a different element. 
    
    my $len = @authrecoutput;
    for (my $i = 0; $i <= $len; $i++){
        if(@authrecoutput[$i] =~ /^AMQ8864I/)  #when the eventcode occurs i start creating a new hash and store all properties in it. 
        {
            my $rec = {};
            while (@authrecoutput[$i+1] =~ /(\S+)\((.+?)\)/g ){
                $rec->{$1} = $2;
            }
            while (@authrecoutput[$i+2] =~ /(\S+)\((.+?)\)/g ){ 
                $rec->{$1} = $2;
            }
            while (@authrecoutput[$i+3] =~ /(\S+)\((.+?)\)/g ){  #problem with this that now the script only looks at $i+3 lines so anything on $1+4 i will miss.  
                $rec->{$1} = $2;
            }
            push @authrecs, $rec; 
        }
    
    }

    print Dumper @authrecs;
```

my output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'AUTHLIST' => 'BROWSE,CHG,CLR,DLT,DSP,GET,INQ,PUT,PASSALL,PASSID,SET,SETALL,SETID',
          'ENTTYPE' => 'GROUP',
          'ENTITY' => 'GROUP1',
          'OBJTYPE' => 'QUEUE',
          'PROFILE' => 'SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE'
        };
$VAR2 = {
          'PROFILE' => 'SYSTEM.MQEXPLORER.REPLY.MODEL',
          'ENTITY' => 'GROUP1',
          'OBJTYPE' => 'QUEUE',
          'ENTTYPE' => 'GROUP'
        };
$VAR3 = {
          'PROFILE' => 'self',
          'OBJTYPE' => 'QMGR',
          'ENTITY' => 'GROUP1',
          'ENTTYPE' => 'GROUP',
          'AUTHLIST' => 'ALTUSR,CHG,CONNECT,DLT,DSP,INQ,SET,SETALL,SETID,CTRL,SYSTEM'
        };
```

This works but the problem is that looking for the properties in the array is not dynamic and is set at a fixed length of @authrecoutput[$i+3]. For example, the 'SYSTEM.MQEXPLORER.REPLY.MODEL' profile has 4 lines in the text output and the fourth line including the 'AUTHLIST'property is obviously not captured.

I tried nesting a second for loop which breaks when the eventcode AMQ8864I occurs again (because that's when I know a new record is being displayed) but i didn't find how to break a for loop on a regex condition, if that is even a thing.

How could i code this to be more dynamically and reads lines until the next occurrence of 'AMQ8864I' is detected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a variable `$inside` as a flag that tells me whether I'm inside a record or not. If I am, I store the tuples into the last hash in the array. When a new section starts, I push an empty hash into the array.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @arr;
my $inside;
while (<DATA>) {
    $inside = 0 unless /^ {4}/;

    if ($inside) {
        $arr[-1]{$1} = $2 while / (\S+)\(([^)]+)\)/g;
    }

    if (/^ AMQ8864I:/) {
        $inside = 1;
        push @arr, {};
    }
}
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@arr;

__DATA__
...
```

Output:

```perl
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'ENTTYPE' => 'GROUP',
            'AUTHLIST' => 'BROWSE,CHG,CLR,DLT,DSP,GET,INQ,PUT',
            'OBJTYPE' => 'QUEUE',
            'PROFILE' => 'SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE',
            'ENTITY' => 'GROUP1'
          },
          {
            'OBJTYPE' => 'QUEUE',
            'ENTITY' => 'GROUP1',
            'PROFILE' => 'SYSTEM.MQEXPLORER.REPLY.MODEL',
            'AUTHLIST' => 'BROWSE,CHG,CLR,DLT,DSP,GET,INQ,PUT',
            'ENTTYPE' => 'GROUP'
          },
          {
            'ENTITY' => 'GROUP1',
            'OBJTYPE' => 'QMGR',
            'PROFILE' => 'self',
            'AUTHLIST' => 'ALTUSR,CHG,CONNECT,DLT,DSP,INQ,SET',
            'ENTTYPE' => 'GROUP'
          }
        ];
```

Comment: Hey thanks for that solution, very useful and it seems i have still much to learn when it comes to writing code short and efficiently :) 
i'm just wondering if it matters that the resulting array of hashes is now structured differently? 
first it was: 
$VAR1={key => value, key => value}; ^$VAR2={...., ....} 
while now everything is on VAR1:
 $VAR1 = [  {....,....  }, {.....,...}{.....}{.....}

does this change how to access individual keys and values?

Comment: No, it's same, I just used `Dumper \@arr` instead of `Dumper @arr`. It's a single variable, after all.

Answer (score 1):

Utilization of *match range operator* provides other approach to the solution.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $id = 'AMQ8864I';
my(%data, $record);

while( <DATA> ) {
    if( /^ $id:/ .. /^\s+AUTHLIST/ ) {
        unless( /^ $id:/ ) {
            $record->{$1} = $2 while /\s+(.+?)\((.*?)\)/g;
        } else {
            push @{$data{$id}}, $record if defined $record;
            $record = undef;
        }
    }
}

push @{$data{$id}}, $record if defined $record;

say Dumper(\%data);

__DATA__
     1 : DISPLAY AUTHREC GROUP('GROUP1')
 AMQ8864I: Display authority record details.
    PROFILE(SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE)     ENTITY(GROUP1)
    ENTTYPE(GROUP)                          OBJTYPE(QUEUE)
    AUTHLIST(BROWSE,CHG,CLR,DLT,DSP,GET,INQ,PUT)
 AMQ8864I: Display authority record details.
    PROFILE(SYSTEM.MQEXPLORER.REPLY.MODEL)
    ENTITY(GROUP1)                         ENTTYPE(GROUP)
    OBJTYPE(QUEUE)
    AUTHLIST(BROWSE,CHG,CLR,DLT,DSP,GET,INQ,PUT)
 AMQ8864I: Display authority record details.
    PROFILE(self)                           ENTITY(GROUP1)
    ENTTYPE(GROUP)                          OBJTYPE(QMGR)
    AUTHLIST(ALTUSR,CHG,CONNECT,DLT,DSP,INQ,SET)
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'AMQ8864I' => [
                          {
                            'ENTTYPE' => 'GROUP',
                            'AUTHLIST' => 'BROWSE,CHG,CLR,DLT,DSP,GET,INQ,PUT',
                            'OBJTYPE' => 'QUEUE',
                            'PROFILE' => 'SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE',
                            'ENTITY' => 'GROUP1'
                          },
                          {
                            'ENTTYPE' => 'GROUP',
                            'ENTITY' => 'GROUP1',
                            'OBJTYPE' => 'QUEUE',
                            'PROFILE' => 'SYSTEM.MQEXPLORER.REPLY.MODEL',
                            'AUTHLIST' => 'BROWSE,CHG,CLR,DLT,DSP,GET,INQ,PUT'
                          },
                          {
                            'ENTTYPE' => 'GROUP',
                            'AUTHLIST' => 'ALTUSR,CHG,CONNECT,DLT,DSP,INQ,SET',
                            'OBJTYPE' => 'QMGR',
                            'PROFILE' => 'self',
                            'ENTITY' => 'GROUP1'
                          }
                        ]
        };
```

Comment: Hey thank you for this solution. 
I didn't know the range operator also worked with patterns.  
The only downside to this is that i would like to reuse this code to store similar text output from different DISPLAY commands, so the data will not always end with the AUTHLIST property. 
Is there maybe a way to capture what is between the  AMQ8864I events? 
the reason i'm asking is because MQ always displays the display commands in the same structure but with different event numbers: AMQ8XXX ....record .... AMQ8XXX .... record .... AMQ8XXX ... record ... AMQ8XXX.

Comment: Without seeing full sample of input data impossible predict best approach to the problem. The pattern can be adjusted to be `AMQ8\d{4}\w{1}` to match mentioned by you. The range  operator triggered on matching ending block _AUTHLIST_. If there is any other data it will require adjustment for algorithm (original post had all blocks ending with _AUTHLIST_). There should be some indicator that block is finished -- for some it will be start of next _AMQ8XXXX_ block, but what about very very last block -- what would indicate that if finished?